# Como eu faço para colocar um select dentro do while?

Tags: php, mysql

Uso Sublime text, Mysql Workbench e Xampp.

Eu fiz um inner join no select abaixo, em uma tabela chamada Organizacoes.Copia. Nessa tabela tem um campo chamado "id" e eu preciso que ele apareça nesse código do Php.

Vi vários vídeos e exemplos, e não consegui fazer. Como eu coloco pra que puxe a cópia desses clientes que retornam na minha variável "`$result`"? Como incluo isso no while?

Segue o código pronto:

```
<?php

$servidor = '****';
$user = '****';
$senha = '****';
$banco = 'Organizacoes';

// Cria conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servidor, $user, $senha, $banco);
// Checa conexão
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexão falha: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT   Org.id
        ,Org.nome 
        FROM Organizacoes as Org 

        INNER JOIN Organizacoes.Rel_Organizacoes as Grupo on Org.id = Grupo.id_Organizacao
        INNER JOIN Organizacoes.Copias as Copia on Org.id = Copia.id_Organizacao

        WHERE  Grupo.id_grupo = 210 
        GROUP BY Org.id
        ORDER BY Org.id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo " <tr>";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // dados de saída de cada linha
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - nome: " . $row["nome"]. " " . "<br>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: a query traz os resultados?

Comment: Traz, ela trás o nome de cliente e o código dele.. Essa "cópia" é um id, mas de outra tabela. Mas não consigo incluir esse campo "Id.Copia nesse while atual.

Comment: é porque vc não pediu pro select trazer ele

Comment: Então, na verdade eu tirei pra postar aqui porque não consigo montar no while.. Se eu colocar na minha variável $result select Org.id
        ,Org.nome , Copia.id .. Como eu vou colocar pra ele aparecer no while? Como que eu estruturo? Essa parte que to tendo dificuldade sabe?

Comment: Ficarei muito grata.. Percebi que é a dúvida de muitos iniciantes em php.

Comment: apaguei sem querer, meu mouse ta no fim da vida ja

Comment: chama o id que vc quer e da um `var_dump($result)` e veja como ficou a estruturação

Comment: Então eu adiciono o id.copia na minha variável $result, e coloco o "var_dump ($result) " depois do while? Onde eu deixo ele?

Comment: Teria como eu colocar uma "query2" com "$result2" dentro desse while? Ou você acha que é melhor fazer do jeito que vc disse?

Comment: pode ser antes do while, desde que seja dps que $result apareceu

Comment: Deu certo o var_dump?

Comment: Deu em partes.. Ele puxou a cópia, mas substituiu meu outro id de clientes..

Comment: então o problema esta na nomenclatura dos campos das tablas, esta com nomes iguais, basta alterar

Comment: assim vc consegue separar dentro do $row['id_copia'] do $row['id']

Comment: Mas como vou fazer isso? Se eu alterar o nome ele dá erro: Notice: Undefined index: ['id_copia'] in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php on line 29

Comment: O nome dos campos são iguais, mas as tabelas são diferentes. TabA.id, TabB.id.. Entendeu?

Comment: Poste o retorno do var_dump

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, você poderia usar essa solução. Não sei se no php estaria correto, mas na query pode ser essa solução.

```
<?php

$servidor = '****';
$user = '****';
$senha = '****';
$banco = 'Organizacoes';

// Cria conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servidor, $user, $senha, $banco);
// Checa conexão
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexão falha: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Copia.*,  Org.id
    ,Org.nome 
    FROM Organizacoes as Org 

    INNER JOIN Organizacoes.Rel_Organizacoes as Grupo on Org.id = Grupo.id_Organizacao
    INNER JOIN Organizacoes.Copias as Copia on Org.id = Copia.id_Organizacao

    WHERE  Grupo.id_grupo = 210 
    GROUP BY Org.id
    ORDER BY Org.id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo " <tr>";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // dados de saída de cada linha
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"].  "id_Copia: " . $row["Copia.id"]. " - nome: " . $row["nome"]. " " . "<br>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Então, no mysql a query até funciona.. Mas puxaria todos os dados da tabela cópia, e eu precisava só do id. 

No php, ele dá erro: Notice: Undefined index: Copia.id in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php on line 39
id: 1044 id_Copia: - nome: EXEMPLO CLIENTE 1

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim

```
$sql="
    SELECT
        Copia.id AS copia_id,
        Org.id,
        Org.nome 
        FROM Organizacoes as Org 

        INNER JOIN Organizacoes.Rel_Organizacoes as Grupo on Org.id = Grupo.id_Organizacao
        INNER JOIN Organizacoes.Copias as Copia on Org.id = Copia.id_Organizacao

        WHERE  Grupo.id_grupo = 210 
        GROUP BY Org.id
        ORDER BY Org.id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo " <tr>";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // dados de saída de cada linha
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " copia-id: " . $row["copia_id"]. " - nome: " . $row["nome"]. " " . "<br>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Deu certinho Wess Smith.. Resultado: id: 110 copia-id: 8451 - nome: CLIENTE 2.  Posso só fazer uma última pergunta?

Comment: claro, quando quiser

Comment: Essa id_copia, eu preciso do id mais recente. Sabe me indicar alguma função que eu possa usar? Eu até tentei o max(id_copia), mas ele respeita somente pra alguns..

Comment: ORDER BY Org.id, Copia.id DESC

Comment: Respeita em alguns somente.. Quando você me orientou a utilizar o var_dump ele puxou certinho

Comment: como assim em alguns?

Comment: Por exemplo, tenho o Cliente 5.. Esse cliente tem duas copia.id. (Uma de 2011 e outra de 2018). Ele mostra Cliente 5 - E a cópia de 2011. Daí tem o Cliente 2 que tem duas cópias tbm (2015 e 2017). Dai ele mostra: Cliente 2 - Copia de 2017 (correta, pq é a última).. Entendeu?

Comment: entendi sim, mas na tabela o id do 2011 ta menor ou maior q 2018?

Comment: confirma, porque as vezes é esse o BOzinho

Comment: Então, o id dá de 2011 é 1195.. E o id da de 2018 é 1660. As duas atreladas ao Cliente 5.

Comment: tenta colocar um ORDER BY Org.id, Copia.id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Com o Limit 1 ele só vai puxar 1 único cliente.. Coloquei no where pra ser o "Cliente 5" que está com esse problema e ele continua puxando a cópia de 2011. Estranho ele não respeitar né..

Comment: sim, mto estranho, porque como vc colocou DESC ele ja automaticamente pegaria o ultimo

Comment: Pois é.. Tentei e estou tentando várias maneiras e não dá certo.